# Does YamlDotNet library support the document separator?

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, yamldotnet

This `YAML` file:

```
---
- Prisoner
- Goblet
- Phoenix
---
- Memoirs
- Snow 
- Ghost
```

is deserializing by this code:

```
var input = new StreamReader (path)
var deserializer = new Deserializer();
var lis = deserializer.Deserialize <List <string>> (input);
```

Result is Exception in `YamlDotNet.dll`:

```
(Line: 5, Col: 4, Idx: 136): Expected 'StreamEnd', 
got 'DocumentStart' (at Line: 5, Col: 1, Idx: 133).
```

**Update1:** SharpYaml: the same exception

**Update2:** 
@DarrelMiller: Yes, it is not clear from my first example, but the need of document separator is seen in second example:

```
---
- Prisoner
- Goblet
- Phoenix
---
- Memoirs: [213, 2004]
- Snow: [521, 2011] 
- Ghost: [211, 2002]
```

So I needed the separator to change the type for the `Deserializer`.

@AntoineAubry: Thanks for answer and YamlDotNet, I like them both.

Comment: try removing second instance of "---" on line 5

Comment: It does support multiple documents using the YamlStream class.  However, I suspect the deserializer is only expecting one document.  It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve with two documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily deserialize more than one document. In order to do that, you need to use the [Deserialize() overload that takes an EventReader](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/Deserializer.cs#L149):

```
public void Main()
{
    var input = new StringReader(Document);

    var deserializer = new Deserializer();

    var reader = new Parser(input);

    // Consume the stream start event "manually"
    reader.Consume<StreamStart>();

    // Deserialize the first document
    var firstSet = deserializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);

    Console.WriteLine("## First document");
    foreach(var item in firstSet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    // Deserialize the second document
    var secondSet = deserializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);

    Console.WriteLine("## Second document");
    foreach(var item in secondSet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }   
}
```

[Here's a fully working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XEVomx).

You can even read any number of documents by using a loop:

```
while(reader.Accept<DocumentStart>())
{
    // Deserialize the document
    var doc = deserializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(reader);

    Console.WriteLine("## Document");
    foreach(var item in doc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qy4Gse)

Comment: could you possibly update this to a working post 4.0 version?

Comment: Done, but did you attempt to run that code ? I only had to remove the `EventReader` part.